# Can I specify which host will have which rank in an MPI program?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I'm using MPI to execute a parallel job over a heterogeneous compute system. The nodes in my network are not all identical.

I would like to specify that machine 'A.univ.edu' has rank 0 and machine 'B.univ.edu' has rank 1.

Is there any way to specify how ranks are assigned to hosts in MPI?

Comment: Rank assignment in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is controlled by `mpiexec`.  The details differ a bit between MPI implementations, so refer to the man page.  In the example with the two hosts, you would just list them in that order in the machinefile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like at least OpenMPI allows you to specify a rankfile

The above example would be as follows

```
rankfile.txt:
rank 0=A.univ.edu slot=0
rank 1=B.univ.edu slot=0

mpiexec -np 2 -H A.univ.edu,B.univ.edu -rf rankfile.txt executable.exe
```

http://mirror.its.dal.ca/openmpi/doc/v1.5/man1/mpiexec.1.php#sect9

Comment: Are you aware of a similar mechanism for MPICH?

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, you can always use `MPI_Comm_split` to create a new communicator in which your processes all have the desired rank. After each process has determined its intended rank (stored in, say, `newRank`), a call to `MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0, newRank, newComm)` will create a communicator in `newComm` with the proper ordering. You can then use that communicator instead of `MPI_COMM_WORLD` in all your communication calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "-rank-by node" switch. This will cause the processes to be mapped in the order the hosts were specified.